# Contar los valores de la columna title por cada país, solo del año 2017 y 2018 ( por separado)

Tags: python, pandas, vscode

Contar la cantidad de la columna `title` por cada país durante el año 2017 y 2018 (por separado los años)

````
DATAFRAME
```df = df.reindex(columns=['date','trending_date','year','country','title','channel_title','views','likes','dislikes','description','thumbnail_link','tags','comments_disabled','video_error_or_removed','video_id'])```
```df```
```df.year.unique()```
array([2017, 2009, 2016, 2014, 2015, 2013, 2008, 2010, 2018, 2012, 2011,
       2007, 2006], dtype=int64) 

```df.country.unique()```
array(['CA', 'DE', 'FR', 'GB', 'IN', 'US'], dtype=object)
````

Con este `groupby` solo me aparece el desglose por países y el total de la cantidad y quiero que me aparezca el desglose: años 2017 y 2018, países y la cantidad total.

````
```country_split= df.groupby("country")["year"].count()```

```df.info()```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 239703 entries, 0 to 239702
Data columns (total 15 columns):
 #   Column                  Non-Null Count   Dtype              
---  ------                  --------------   -----              
 0   date                    239703 non-null  datetime64[ns, UTC]
 1   trending_date           239703 non-null  object             
 2   year                    239703 non-null  int64              
 3   country                 239703 non-null  object             
 4   title                   239703 non-null  object             
 5   channel_title           239703 non-null  object             
 6   views                   239703 non-null  int64              
 7   likes                   239703 non-null  int64              
 8   dislikes                239703 non-null  int64              
 9   description             239703 non-null  object             
 10  thumbnail_link          239703 non-null  object             
 11  tags                    239703 non-null  object             
 12  comments_disabled       239703 non-null  bool               
 13  video_error_or_removed  239703 non-null  bool               
 14  video_id                239703 non-null  object
````

Gracias!

Comment: Agrega lo que has intentado, las preguntas de tipo este es mi deber resuélvanlo no son bien recibidas.

Comment: No figura la columna que indicas en tu dataframe, y adicionalmente deberías considerar formatear el texto como código

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tu dataframe sea, por ejemplo, el siguiente:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "year": [2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020],
        "country": ["ES", "ES", "DE", "DE", "UK", "DE", "UK"],
        "title": ["A", "B", "A", "D", "C", "C", "C"],
    }
)
```

`df` quedaría así:

```
   year country title
0  2018      ES     A
1  2018      ES     B
2  2019      DE     A
3  2019      DE     D
4  2019      UK     C
5  2019      DE     C
6  2020      UK     C
```

#### Para contar el número de valores de *title* (o número de filas) por país y año, hacemos lo siguiente:

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(["country", "year"])["title"].count())
```

`df2` quedaría así:

```
              title
country year       
DE      2019      3
ES      2018      2
UK      2019      1
        2020      1
```

Para ver mejor los datos, pivotamos `df2`:

```py
df3 = df2.pivot_table(values="title", index=["country"], columns=["year"], 
                      fill_value=0)
```

`df3` quedaría así:

```
year     2018  2019  2020
country                  
DE          0     3     0
ES          2     0     0
UK          0     1     1
```

#### Para contar el número de valores de *title* (o número de filas) por país, hacemos lo siguiente:

```py
df4 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby("country")["title"].count())
```

`df4` quedaría así:

```
         title
country       
DE           3
ES           2
UK           2
```

#### Finalmente, para contar el número de valores de *title* (o número de filas) por año, hacemos lo siguiente:

```py
df5 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby("year")["title"].count())
```

`df5` quedaría así:

```
      title
year       
2018      2
2019      4
2020      1
```